# Hourglass while Opening Outlook 365 using Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

We just moved to Outlook 365 which takes forever to open.  I have a program that puts events into the Outlook calendar.  It first checks to see if Outlook is open, and, if it's not, opens it.  I would like an hourglass while it's opening.

I put it in my code, but it looks like that it sees Outlook open as soon as it starts opening, so the hourglass goes away.

Here is the last code modification I tried:

```vb
If IsAppRunning("Outlook.Application") = True Then    'Outlook was already running
    Set objApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Outlook
Else    'Could not get instance of Outlook, so create a new one
    sAPPPath = GetAppExePath("outlook.exe")    'determine outlook's installation path
    Shell (sAPPPath)    'start outlook
    Do While Not IsAppRunning("Outlook.Application")
        DoEvents
        DoCmd.Hourglass True  ' turn on Hourglass
    Loop
    If IsAppRunning("Outlook.Application") = True Then
        Set objApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Outlook
        DoCmd.Hourglass False ' turn off hourglass
    End If
End If
```

And the functions that go with it:

```vb
Function IsAppRunning(sApp As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim oApp            As Object
 
    Set oApp = GetObject(, sApp)
    IsAppRunning = True
 
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = Nothing
    Exit Function
 
Error_Handler:
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function

Function GetAppExePath(ByVal sExeName As String) As String
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim WSHShell        As Object
 
    Set WSHShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    GetAppExePath = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\" & sExeName & "\")
 
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WSHShell = Nothing
    Exit Function
 
Error_Handler:
    If Err.Number = -2147024894 Then
        'Cannot locate requested exe????
    Else
        MsgBox "The following error has occurred." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Source: GetAppExePath" & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Description: " & Err.Description, _
               vbCritical, "An Error has Occurred!"
    End If
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Comment: Set the hourglass *before* you open Outlook.

Comment: Set hourglass before and after the outer If Then Else block.

Comment: Nope - didn't work.  And I did discover that even if Outlook opens, you can't get to the Calendar right away.  With Office 365 becoming more popular, someone has had to have this problem.